# Is it possible for an app to prevent the keyboard from learning words on Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, textbox, android-softkeyboard

I am developing an Android application (Xamarin Forms) where the user will be entering personal and potentially sensitive information. I would like to prevent the keyboard from "learning" words that the user enters into the application.

I know it is possible for the user to manually delete learned words from their phone (as explained here: https://trendblog.net/delete-learned-words-android-keyboard/ ) but is it possible for an application, or specifically text entries, to tell Android to not learn from entered text?

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Forms [`Entry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry), try turning off text prediction:

```
<Entry ... IsTextPredictionEnabled="false" />
```

I don't know whether that also disables "remembering" what you type. Try it, and leave a comment whether that worked.

---

If no cross-platform solution is suggested, then you'll need to make a "custom renderer" for Entry, in your .Android project.

There, behavior is controlled by the [input type](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:inputType).

Try `visible password` or maybe `no suggestions`. (not sure exactly what those are in xamarin, but intellisense will show you the options, at the right place in the custom renderer's code.)

Comment: I don't know how reliable my testing is, because I haven't been able to get my phone to learn things I type. I expect it can, but I don't know how to trigger it.